# how Remove double quotes from a string ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, implicit-conversion

how Remove double quotes from a string ruby on rails ?
I have a string like:

```
"5,5"
```

conversion logic :

```
@a = @cart_id.chomp(',')
abort @a.inspect
```

Comment: Try this-

str="\"1,2,3,4\""
str.gsub!('"', '')
puts str
# 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = 'hello " 5," world'

str.gsub!('"', '')

puts str #hello  5, world
```